# 3 colums in footer - right side alignment bug

Tags: html, css

In order to divide my footer into 3 columns I have to use negative margin on the third column.
I believe there is another way which doesn't require forcing this column into position.

**HTML:**

```
<footer>
    <div class="fLeft">
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fCenter">
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
    </div>
    <div class="fRight">
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
        <p>Link</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS:**

```css
footer{
    background:#2c2c2c;
    height:200px;
    border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
    margin:40px 20px 0 20px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
}

.fLeft{
    margin:10px 0 0 10px;
    float:left;
    width: 33.3%;
    text-align:center;
}

.fCenter{
    margin:10px 0 0 0;
    float:left;
    width: 33.3%;
    text-align:center;
}

.fRight{
    margin:-160px 10px 0 0;
    float:right;
    width: 33.3%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EbvJV/1/)**

You can see there error I get, but `-160px`is a fix for me and `-80px` is the fix on fiddle.

Comment: Why are you changing the top margins? Wouldn't something like this be more what you want http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EbvJV/2/?

Comment: OK, I'll make that an answer and you can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the CSS to be more like the following to get the effect you're after.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EbvJV/2/)**

**CSS**

```
footer{
background:#2c2c2c;
height:200px;
border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
margin:40px 20px 0 20px;
color:#FFFFFF;
}

.fLeft{
float:left;
width: 33%;
text-align:center;
}

.fCenter{
width: 33%;
text-align:center;
    float:left;
}

.fRight{
float:right;
width: 33%;
text-align:center;
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are pushing the right column to the next line. You have a width of 33.3% on each column, but you also have a left margin on `.fLeft` and a right margin on `.fRight` of 10px causing the width of all together to be more than the 100% that you want to fit everything in. If you remove these two margins you will see the columns line up properly. If you want to keep these margins you will have to change your widths.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you are looking for:

http://jsfiddle.net/t5Xhj/

you shouldnt use margins

```
footer{
background:#2c2c2c;
height:200px;
border-radius: 25px 25px 0 0;
margin:40px 20px 0 20px;
color:#FFFFFF;
}

.fLeft{
float:left;
width: 33.3%;
text-align:center;
}

.fCenter{
float:left;
width: 33.3%;
text-align:center;
}

.fRight{
 float:right;
 width: 33.3%;
 text-align:center;
}​
```

Comment: yea, that is good but I want there to be space between the top of the footer and the top line of text

Comment: @weewa you can use padding-top to create space